# Show list element as a selected item from dropdown

Tags: jquery, html

I have a dropdown menu that is built off a `ul` and `li`. The challenge I am facing is when I am selecting a list item I can show it as selected item in the drop down but it changing its position from the list. I would like to keep the item that is selected at the same position but would like to show it as a selection for the dropdown. Same was an `<select>` `<option>` works but only with `ul li`.

The JS looks like this:

```
var $accordion = $('.dropdown ul');

$accordion.click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).children().show();
  $(this).on('click', function() {
    $(this).children().each(function() {
      if ($(this).index() !== 0) {
        $(this).toggle();
      }
    });
  });

  $('li').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().prepend($(this));
  })
});
```

[Here is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/ccnj1qa8/).

Comment: Can you repeat your question please?!

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan -- you realize I am not using a plugin right? You have anything to add to this solution?

Comment: That was kind of the point. Why reinvent the wheel? If you must make the same mistakes over again, I suggest you look into [jQuery patterns for plugins](https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-patterns) as they make thinking about what your element (and its children) is doing much easier. For instance, you have `$(this)` all over the place; it might not refer to what you think it refers to, and makes it harder to reason about the code.

Comment: I have studied both your `javascript` and `CSS` code with care. Considering what would pass as *decent* levels in usability, responsiveness, cross-browser/cross-device compatibility your code is quite far from production level. You would have quite a lot to gain by studying how the most popular of the above mentioned libraries do it. If anyone is going to answer this, their answer will either do what I suggested you do (reverse engineer - but you won't learn as much if you don't do it yourself), or will not come close it terms of code quality and performance.

Comment: Besides, stating *"I'm not using a plugin"* when using jQuery... is going to make a few coders smile. Being ironic when asking for help never helps.